# unable to send email from my application

Tags: android

I have a requirement that I need to send email from my application, I am using below code to send email...

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("Text/Plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{abc@gmail.com});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello..");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, email_chooser_title));
```

The above code launching the email composer. But after I press on send button , I can see one toast message "Message Sending" , But my message not sent.

pl. help me to figure out where I did wrong in this, or let me know if any alternative to solve this..  thanks.

Comment: You are testing your app in phone ?.. if yes then Make sure that your Background Services are ON..

Comment: karthik , yes I am testing it on phone. I am unable to understand your phrase "Make sure that your Background Services are ON.".. can you pl. elaborate this..??

Comment: It means whether your phone's background services (Sync)are On or Off.. If its Off, your app will simply Toast message and it will wait for background services to start. When background services will start, it will send mail.If you have Samsung Android Mobile then Go to Settings -> Accounts & Sync-> BackgroundData (Enable/Disable)..

Comment: You can check my blog as well [Android Email Sending Code Snippet](http://hossaindoula.blogspot.com/2011/06/sending-email-from-android-code-snippet.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    //i.setType("text/plain"); //use this line for testing in the emulator
    i.setType("message/rfc822") ; // use from live device
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"test@gmail.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"subject goes here");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"body goes here");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select email application."));
```